# composer require --update-no-dev zyberspace/telegram-cli-client

Tags: php

Please refer this link https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client

I am trying to install it by using this command:

```
composer require --update-no-dev zyberspace/telegram-cli-client
```

but linux prompt displays message:

```
-bash: composer: command not found
[root@serverName httpdocs]# yum install composer
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            |  14 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirror.denit.net
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * updates: mirror.denit.net
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 5.7 MB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
No package composer available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: composer.jason already exists in project root directory. I am unable to understand how can I test this API https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client as I am not related to php but java

Comment: # curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /var/www/vhosts/domanName.com/httpdocs/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

# composer require --update-no-dev zyberspace/telegram-cli-client
-bash: composer: command not foun

Comment: Still waiting for any response to fix my problem